Enforcing eslint "react/require-default-props" for arrow function components
In my react project, I am using eslint with eslint-plugin-react and have set the following rule:
"react/require-default-props": ["warn", {
    "forbidDefaultForRequired": true,
    "classes": "defaultProps",
    "functions": "defaultArguments"
}]

The "functions": "defaultArguments" piece gives me a warning when I try to define default props like this:
function MyComponent({ value }) {
  return <div>...</div>;
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  value: '',
};

Don’t use defaultProps with function components. eslint(react/require-default-props)
and instead requires me to define the default values in the function arguments like this:
function MyComponent({ value = '' }) {
  return <div>...</div>;
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

However, when I have a function declaration component instead (using an arrow function with const), I do not get this warning, but would like to:
const MyComponent = forwardRef(({ value }, ref) => {
  return <div>...</div>;
});

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent';

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  value: PropTypes.string,
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  value: '',
};

Is there a rule I can set or something so that eslint will warn me to not use defaultProps in this scenario and to put the default prop values in the arguments like it is doing for the function components?
